# Get time difference for consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example: I have two columns in a `select` statement, one is some `id` & the other is a `Datetime` column.

What I want is a third column that indicates the time difference one after another row.

```
IdColumn      DateTimeColumn         DifferenceColumn 
-----------------------------------------------------
   1          2014-12-31 14:14:55.050        0
   2          2014-12-31 16:14:55.050        2
   3          2014-12-31 19:14:55.050        3
   4          2014-12-31 21:14:55.050        2
```

Here the `DifferenceColumn` is in hours difference of each row one over another.

How can I achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: Which is the version of SQL Server you're using?

Answer (score 2):

use **[SELF join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490(v=sql.105).aspx)** .

```
   SELECT T1.IdColumn, T1.DateTimeColumn, 
          ISNULL(DATEDIFF(hour, t2.DateTimeColumn , t1.DateTimeColumn), 0) as Diff 
   FROM #Test AS T1 LEFT JOIN #Test AS T2 
   ON t1.IdColumn = t2.IdColumn + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Lead Function` if you are using `Sql server 2012+`

```
SELECT IdColumn,
       DateTimeColumn,
       isnull(Datediff(hh, Lead(DateTimeColumn)OVER(ORDER BY IdColumn) DifferenceColumn, DateTimeColumn),0) 
From Tablename
```

For earlier Versions use the below queries.

**Method 1:** `Self Join`

```
SELECT a.IdColumn,
       a.DateTimeColumn,
       Isnull(Datediff(hh, b.DateTimeColumn, a.DateTimeColumn), 0) DifferenceColumn
FROM   tablename a
       LEFT JOIN tablename b
              ON a.IdColumn = b.IdColumn + 1
```

**Method 2:** `Correlated Subquery`

```
SELECT IdColumn,
       DateTimeColumn,
       Isnull((SELECT TOP 1 Datediff(hh, b.DateTimeColumn, a.DateTimeColumn)
               FROM   Tablename b
               WHERE  a.idcolumn > b.IdColumn
               ORDER  BY IdColumn DESC), 0) AS DifferenceColumn
FROM   Tablename a
```

Comment: This of course *only* works in SQL Server **2012** or newer - earlier versions didn't have a `LEAD` function

Comment: @marc_s - yes Marc you are right. Updated to work with earlier versions

Comment: I m running sql server 2008.

Comment: @user3264939 - So use the second query (self join)

Answer (score 0):

CTE May help you. Please refer below SQL:

```
insert into test values (1,'1-12-2002');
insert into test values (2,'2-12-2003');
insert into test values (3,'3-12-2004');


with cte as
(SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) row,
  Id    , doj
 FROM test)


SELECT 
   a.Id     ,
   DATEDIFF ( month , b.doj , a.doj) as 'diffmonth'
FROM
   cte a
   LEFT  JOIN cte b
   on  a.row = b.row+1
```